# ggvis plots with ISO/IEC 8859-1

Tags: r, ggvis

The default encoding for R is ISO/IEC 8859-1 which allows me to work with data containing letters such as å ä ö. However, ggvis does not allow such letters.

EDIT: Session info included

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_0.1.0 ggvis_0.4.2  dplyr_0.4.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2     digest_0.6.8    assertthat_0.1  mime_0.4        R6_2.1.1        xtable_1.8-0    jsonlite_0.9.16 DBI_0.3.1       magrittr_1.5   
[10] lazyeval_0.1.10 tools_3.2.3     shiny_0.12.2    httpuv_1.3.3    parallel_3.2.3  htmltools_0.2.6
```

As expected, there is no problem using the r plot

```
data <- data.frame(Ålder = c(24:34), x = c(1:11))

plot(data$Ålder, data$x)
```

[image: With r plot]
However, when using ggvis to do the same Å is replaced with a question mark

```
data %>%
  ggvis(~Ålder, ~x)%>%
  layer_points()
```

[image: With ggvis plot]

Is it possible to use ggvis with ISO/IEC 8859-1 encoding?

Comment: Your ggvis example works fine for me, 64-bit R 3.2.3 on windows.

Comment: I updated R to 3.2.3 but the Å is still a question mark...

Comment: Are you using RStudio?  Maybe add your `sessionInfo()` to the question?  Here's a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476182/special-symbols-in-ggvis-no2), which was never answered.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Rstudio. Thanks, I added session info.

Comment: FYI, I can reproduce this behavior on my old 32-bit machine...

Comment: So basically the problem seem to stem from system being 32-bit? Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior may appear on 32-bit machines.