# GoogleVis garbled characters output

Tags: r, d3.js, character-encoding, ggvis

My `ggVis` outputs have garbled characters.
I imagine there is a mismatch between the encoding settings of my system (Windows 7 -windows ISO8859-1 (I live in Western Europe) and the encoding of GVIS page (utf-8, Firefox or Chrome).

I tried to change the language preferences of R -Studio (system -> utf8) but without success.
Does anyone have any idea?

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

 locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup system locale. For Windows this needs to be done like this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","en_GB.UTF-8")
```

Comment: I have this warning : In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_EN.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_EN.UTF-8" cannot be honored and there is no change...

Comment: Oh, my apologies! Misprinted... It's either en_US.UTF-8 or en_GB.UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry but not working...Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_GB.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_GB.UTF-8" cannot be honored

Comment: Same happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271457/ggvis-plots-with-iso-iec-8859-1. Do you have 32-bit version of Windows?

Comment: 64 bits - my local settings are (french) ISO8859-1

Comment: I completed my question with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Try to update R to 3.2.3 (released on 2015-12-10). Also you've mentioned Chrome - do you have View -> Encoding -> Auto Detect checked up in Chrome? Just in case :) And then your info says that you are running 64-bit version of Windows on 32-bit platform. I am not sure that these are related, but in the link above same problem was reproduced on 32-bit old machine.

Comment: It is a new pc with i5-4300U cpu!

Comment: Didn't mean to offense in any way, friend :) Did you try to make same plot using base system, for instance? Will it show normal words, without questions?

Comment: Then it looks like the problem is with ggVis implementation. If I'll have any fresh ideas on how to help, I'll come back.

Comment: in Chrome works fine with Occident 8859-1 encoding settings! (not automatic detection...)